# Python - tkinter 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xview''

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm trying to place a scrollbar on a `DISABLED` `Entry` widget. However it keeps coming up with the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xview'`. Is it because no value is being returned or should the widget appear regardless of whether or not a value is being returned?

Below is the code for my program; I have commented out the code for the scrollbar:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = int(binary.get(), 2)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    decimal.set(value)

root = Tk()
root.title("Binary to Decimal Converter")
root.wm_iconbitmap("python-xxl.ico")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

binary = StringVar()
decimal = StringVar()

binary_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 30, textvariable = binary)
binary_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = (W, E))

decimalView = ttk.Entry(mainframe, state = DISABLED, background = "gray99", width = 30, textvariable = decimal).grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = W)
"""scrollbar = Scrollbar(mainframe, orient = HORIZONTAL, command = decimalView.xview)
scrollbar.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (N, S, E, W))
decimalView.config(command = scrollbar.set)"""
ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Calculate", command = calculate).grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Binary").grid(column = 3, row = 1, sticky = W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Decimal").grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx = 5, pady = 5)

binary_entry.focus()
root.bind("<Return>", calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was following the official tutorial for it http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html#scrollbar

Comment: For reference I did it exactly their way and it still comes with the same error and according to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm) `xview` is a method for the `Entry` widget.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `grid` returns `None`, not `self`.

So, when you do this:

```
decimalView = ttk.Entry(mainframe, state = DISABLED, background = "gray99", width = 30, textvariable = decimal).grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = W)
```

… you're setting `decimalView` to `None`. Which is why the error message tells you that it can't find an `xview` attribute on `None`.

And this isn't some weird quirk of Tkinter; almost every method in Python that mutates an object in any way returns `None` (or, sometimes, some other useful value—but never `self`), from `list.sort` to `file.write`.

Just write it on two lines: construct the `Entry` and assign it to `decimalView`, and then `grid` it.

Besides the minor benefit of having working code, you'll also have more readable code, that doesn't scroll off the right side of the screen on StackOverflow or most text editors.

Comment: I hate it when people accept, but don't give a +1. +1 man, you deserve it.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was driving me insane. But I don't understand why it returns `None` rather than `self`. What is the difference between putting `.grid` on another line rather on the same line for it to return `self`?

Comment: @RoyalSwish: Putting `grid` onto another line doesn't make it return self; if you wrote the second line as `decimalView = decimalView.grid(…)`, that would still set it to `None`. But you wouldn't do that, would you? (I _know_ you wouldn't, because when you called `grid` on `mainframe`, `binary_entry`, etc., you didn't.)

Comment: @RoyalSwish: As for why Python was designed that way, there are multiple reasons, too complicated to explain in an SO comment. But a really brief, inaccurate summary: It makes the errors in mixing up mutating vs. non-mutating methods obvious (they show up on the line that's wrong, not 30 lines later in another function). It encourages a "one thing changes in every line" style of coding. Together with the language syntax, it allows a clean separation of expressions and statements. It discourages overly-long lines of code and encourages a more readable spacing pattern. And more.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: I think new users can't upvote answers to their questions until they hit a certain rep.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you. And @GamesBrainiac I upvoted his answer, I will take that in to consideration next time.