# NoneType object has no attribute yview

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

first of all I want to get it out of the way that I am aware of this question: [Python - tkinter 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xview''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255216/python-tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-xview)

However, after reading this I am still confused as to what the issue is. I have a program that uses Tkinter. In it, there are two text boxes that the user can type text into. I want those boxes to be scrollable. However, I have an issue with doing this. Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("TexComp")
    window.geometry("500x500")
    window.resizable(height=FALSE,width=FALSE)

    windowBackground = '#E3DCA8'

    window.configure(bg=windowBackground)

    instruction = Label(text="Type or paste your text into one box,\nthen paste the text you want to compare it too\ninto the other one.", bg=windowBackground).place(x=115, y=10)

    text1 = Text(width=25).pack(side=LEFT)
    text2 = Text(width=25).pack(side=RIGHT)

    scroll1y=Scrollbar(window, command=text1.yview).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, pady=65)
    scroll2y=Scrollbar(window, command=text2.yview).pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, pady=65)

    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I try to run this, I get an error saying "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'yview'" on the scroll1y and scroll2y scrollbars. I am unsure as to why this is and have been unable to find a clear answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is a very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625407/nonetype-error-self-widget-insert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `grid`, `pack`, and `place` methods of every Tkinter widget work in-place (they always return `None`).  Meaning, you need to call them on their own lines:

```
from Tkinter import *

def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("TexComp")
    window.geometry("500x500")
    window.resizable(height=FALSE,width=FALSE)

    windowBackground = '#E3DCA8'

    window.configure(bg=windowBackground)

    instruction = Label(text="Type or paste your text into one box,\nthen paste the text you want to compare it too\ninto the other one.", bg=windowBackground)
    instruction.place(x=115, y=10)

    text1 = Text(width=25)
    text1.pack(side=LEFT)
    text2 = Text(width=25)
    text2.pack(side=RIGHT)

    scroll1y=Scrollbar(window, command=text1.yview)
    scroll1y.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, pady=65)
    scroll2y=Scrollbar(window, command=text2.yview)
    scroll2y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, pady=65)

    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```